# add button to tinymce

Tags: tinymce, buttons

i have the following method to insert a button in Tinymce editor:

in funcitons.php:

```
class myclaff 
    {
        function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_init', array($this, 'load_tinymceee') );
        }

        function load_tinymceee() {  
           if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) &&  current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) { 
            //i have done as one plugin has only 1 button

            add_filter('mce_external_plugins', array($this, 'add_myplugin_first'));
            add_filter('mce_buttons_3', array($this,'register_mybutton_first') );

            add_filter('mce_external_plugins', array($this, 'add_myplugin_second'));            
            add_filter('mce_buttons_3', array($this,'register_mybutton_second') ); 
           }  
        }  
        //register first plugin,
        function register_mybutton_first($buttons) {  
           array_push($buttons, '|', "UniqueButtonName1" );  
           return $buttons; 
           }
        function add_myplugin_first($plugin_array) {  
           $plugin_array['firstplugin'] = plugins_url('mypluginfolder/js/mybutton1.php');
                                  //or  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/mybutton1.php';
           return $plugin_array; 
           }


        //register second plugin,
        function register_mybutton_second($buttons) {  
           array_push($buttons, '-',  "UniqueButtonName2" );  
           return $buttons;  
            }
        function add_myplugin_second($plugin_array) {  
            $plugin_array['secondplugin'] = plugins_url('mypluginfolder/js/mybutton2.php');
           return $plugin_array;  
            }


    } // class ends

//load class
$blablaa = new myclaff();
```

then inside "mypluginfolder/js/" i have such mybutton1.php *(and mybutton2.php, with the similar code)*

*(i know that i need to enter the correct url of my tinymce button's image)* :

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
error_reporting(0);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../../wp-blog-header.php'); 
?>
(function() {
    // START my customs
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.firstplugin', { 



    init : function(ed, url)
    {

       // ---------- start adding buttons section---------------
        ed.addButton('UniqueButtonName1', {  
            title : 'the title of the button',  
            image : url+'/images/mybuttonimage.png',  
            onclick : function() 
            { 
                    // here starts the output
                txt1 : //just a txt1 labeled block of code
                { 
                var mynam = prompt("<?php echo "Please type your name";?>", "Something Default Name"); 
                ed.selection.setContent('<center>' + mynam + '</center>'); 
                }
            }                   
        });
                },


    // end of the buttons section
        createControl : function(n, cm) {  
            return null;  
        },  
    });  
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('firstplugin', tinymce.plugins.firstplugin);  
})();
```

But when i click on button, i get only javascript popup box, where i can enter only one field. what is the code, to achieve to have multiple fields, boxes, dropdown menus and etc.. after the button click?

Answer (score 2):

Your method is complex... Here is simplest function to add BUTTON in TinyMCE:

(insert this code in funcitons.php):

```
add_action('admin_init', function() {
   if (current_user_can('edit_posts')  &&  get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'register_buttonfirst');
        add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_pluginfirst');
   }
});
function register_buttonfirst($buttons) {  array_push($buttons, "|", "shortcode_button1" );   return $buttons;}
function add_pluginfirst($plugin_array) {$plugin_array['MyPuginButtonTag'] =  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'My_js_folder/1_button.php';return $plugin_array;}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_version', 'my_refresh_mceeee1');  function my_refresh_mceeee1($ver) {$ver += 3;return $ver;}
```

**2) Create 1_button.php in target folder and insert this code   (note, change "wp-load" and "ButtonImage.png" urls!!!)**

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
require('../../../../wp-load.php');
?>
(function() {
    // START my customs
    var abcd =location.host;

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.shortcodebuton_plugin2', {  
        init            : function(ed, this_folder_url)
        {
                    // -------------------------
                    ed.addButton('shortcode_button1', {  
                        title : 'Show Level1 count',  
                        image : this_folder_url + '/ButtonImage.png',
                        onclick : function() {  
                            var vidId = prompt("YouTube Video", "BLABLABLA");
                            ed.selection.setContent(vidId );  
                            //ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'vidId');
                        }  
                    });


        }, 

        createControl   : function(n, cm) {     return null;  }, 
    });  
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('MyPuginButtonTag', tinymce.plugins.shortcodebuton_plugin2);  
})();
```

*p.s.  before you click a button from editor TOOLBAR, at first, you may need to click cursor inside a post editor, otherwise your button may not work.

(for CUSTOM HTML popup, instead of simple prompt, see this example: http://pastebin.com/raw/0BJZm7cd )

Comment: Please use only **one** account. You can answer your own question without a second account.